# Loading the CSS file externally in web component template

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, web-component

I'm using webpack to bundle my project and I want to load the style in my web component template as an external link, so that I can make use of browser caching.

It works well when I'm loading the CSS inline, but I want to avoid doing that, as I feel it is not the best to repeat the large amount of CSS inside the same page.

I have tried the below steps

- Keep the CSS name static - works, but not a feasible solution as it doesn't help with the cache bursting
- Tried exposing the dynamically generated file name as global constant via webpack. it does not work :(

  new webpack.DefinePlugin({PUBLIC_CSS_FILE: JSON.stringify('css/[name].[hash].css'))}

Link to the sample code -> https://github.com/nmakod/web-component

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful